# How many subspaces a vector space of finite dimension over an infinite field has?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

How many subspaces a vector space of finite dimension over an infinite field has? Which formula did you use (In algebra for example you use combinatorics) ? For example the subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ are $\{(0,0)\}$ , the subspace of lines passing for the origin $\{k(x,y) \mid k \in \Bbb R \}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then the collection of all $k$-dimensional linear subspaces is called [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) and denoted $\mathrm{Gr}(k,V)$
. Typically this is an infinite set, but there is well defined notion of dimension or number of degrees of freedom, such that
$$
\dim \mathrm{Gr}(k,V) = k(n-k).
$$
E.g. the lines ($k=1$) in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ have one degree of freedom. The Grassmannian is finite (which is equivalent to it having dimension zero), if and only if $k=0$ or $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite many, except for the trivial vector space of 0 dimension.

For example, all lines passing through the origin are subspaces of a plane.

Comment: So R² is a particular case in which they are a finite number?

Comment: My example of a plane is R^2, and every line passing through the origin is a subspace. Not just the origin as in your question.

Comment: @JohnPi In your subset for lines, notice that you can freely choose $x$ and $y$ to create different lines through the origin, which are all subspaces of $\mathbb R^2.$ To avoid overcounting, consider selecting $x$ and $y$ from points on the unit circle, and notice that you have uncountably many choices. (equal to the number of choices of $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi.$)

Comment: I thought: Lets be V a subspace of R². If V is not equal to {(0,0} then it contains v different from o=(0,0). Then being V close for sum and moltiplication operations, V must contain all v multiples, all the vector of the form k*v, where k is a real number. R*v={k*v| k a real number}. Geometrically speaking it s the subset of all ljnes through the origin. This is a subspace of R². Lets now suppose V is bigger, we add w not belongings to R*v. Every other vector of R² can be seen as the sum of k*v+j*w, j is a real number. Being V close to sum and product, then V=R².

Comment: Ok, now i have understood. If i add an independent vetor of course i obtain R², 2 independent vectors of R² span the vector space. So if i take  k*t where t is a line with a certain gradient i obtain another subspace and if i add to V an independent vector to t i span R².

Answer (score 0):

For $R^1$, it seems to have only two subspace and the trivial vector space too seems to just have one.

$R^2$ also has infinite subspace since $span((1,b))$ for any b is a subspace of $R^2$

Then, obviously $R^n$ With $n>= 2$ has  infinite subspaces. Then for an arbitary finite dimensionsal vector space $V$ with $dim(V)=m$, you can form an isomorphism of it with $R^m$ And thus it too has infinitely many if $m>=2$.

If you need a more geometrical intuition for $R^2$, imagine the x-y plane(flat sheet) of paper and go to the origin and draw a straight line through it. This line is a subspace of $R^2$, then rotate the line about the origin by any angle of your choice, it too is subspace of $R^2$, notice that there are infinite many angles you can choose from. Hope this helps